# What are considered the major film genres?

Tags: genre

I understand this is a little subjective, but I'm trying to categorize all of my movies using an app called Plex, and it's got so many genres listed that it's making things difficult.  So, I'm trying to keep the list small, but relevant.

I've found a list on [this website](http://www.filmsite.org/genres.html) that seems to really narrow it down.  Can anyone add anything to it or give reasons to split it differently?  I'm just trying to list the major categories, I don't need the offshoots like "World Cinema" or "Monster Movie".

- Action
- Adventure
- Comedy
- Crime/Gangster
- Drama
- Epics/Historical
- Horror
- Musicals/Dance
- Sci-Fi
- War
- Westerns

Comment: How about anime, animated, or kids?  Where would those fit?

Comment: Maybe "Romance"?

Comment: @dmikester1 - I probaly need a Childrens/Family genre added here.

Comment: It needs Film Noir

Comment: "Genre" is such a nebulous term that I don't see this question being answered objectively. So I'm voting to close.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about organizing a collection using software.

Comment: @MattD - It's not about organizing a collection using software, I was just using that context.  It's really about which genres are the "major" ones, which I though was on-topic considering we have a tag called "Genre".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your essential list is missing romance, thriller / suspense and fantasy / paranormal.

My suggested list is below,  but it works best if the app you are using allows you to use multiple categories pm movie. In other words a movie could be a romantic comedy (something about mary) ,  an animated family adventure(TinTin)  or a science fiction horror (aliens) or a biopic drama (capone).

- Action
- Adult
- Adventure
- Animation / Anime
- Biopic
- Childrens
- Comedy
- Crime / detective /spy
- Documentary
- Drama
- Horror
- Family
- Fantasy
- Historical
- Medical
- Musical
- Paranormal
- Romance
- Sport
- Science fiction
- Talk Show
- Thriller / Suspense
- War
- Western

I hope that helps. Good luck.

Comment: This helped a lot.  I combined it into my list and between the two I came up with 16 major Genres.  Thanks!

Comment: Talk show? Example, please?

Comment: Talk show: Ellen,  graham norton, etc. I was sharing my personal video file classification and hence this was included because I store various talk shows which don't fit into another genre.  The Graham Norton Show featuring Matt Damon and Bill Murray talking about Monuments Men is funnier and more worth viewing than some recent popular comedies. I see great value in viewing shows that feature the actors and hence I store some in my file collection. I'm using my smartphone so please excuse the deleted post and any typos.

Comment: Talk Shows aren't really film genres...

Comment: @BenPlont I may be new to this, but I thought my English was quite self explanatory, but let me take a stab at answering your comment. Firstly I listed the 3 film genre I thought he should add. Secondly, the name of this stack exchange is "Movies & TV", meaning that it is ok to discuss TV and TV genres on this forum. while Talk Show isn't a film/movie genre, it certainly is a TV genre. Lastly, as noted in my answer and comment, I was sharing a personal way I categorize and classify my video files. I clearly stated this was my "personal" list, not something official.

Comment: @0pinion8d sorry to offend. I mentioned that it's not a film genre because the OPs question specified "what are the major film genres".